# In libclang how to exclude functions from stdio.h

Tags: python, header-files, libclang

When using libclang, how to exclude function from stdio.h ?

When I use the below source to collect only function definitions, then I end up getting all the functions from stdio.h as well.

I read we can pass '-x c-header' kind of arguments while creating index. But does this way of giving arguments applicable in libclang.

```
tu = index.parse(self.filename, "-x c-header")
```

After including 'c-header' argument, it wants me to fill in 'unsaved_files' array as well, as per the definition of 'parse' function in 'cindex.py'.

```
def parse(self, path, args = [], unsaved_files = [], options = 0):
```

I don't know what is the right way to do this.

```
def funcdefn_visitor(self, node, parent, userdata):
    if node.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.FUNCTION_DECL: #gives function definitions
        self.func_defn.append(clang.cindex.Cursor_displayname(node))
        self.func_defn_line_no.append(node.location.line)
        self.func_defn_col_no.append(node.location.column)
    print 'Found %s [line=%s, col=%s]' % (
        clang.cindex.Cursor_displayname(node),
        node.location.line,
        node.location.column)
    return 2 # means continue visiting recursively

index = clang.cindex.Index.create()

tu = index.parse(self.filename)
#-- link cursor visitor to call back to give function definitions
clang.cindex.Cursor_visit(
    tu.cursor,
    clang.cindex.Cursor_visit_callback(self.funcdefn_visitor),
    None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-x c-header` command-line switch is used to generate [precompiled headers](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#precompiled-headers), not to exclude headers from the translation unit.

I think the correct way to exclude functions from a specific file would be to skip all nodes located in it while visiting the AST. To elaborate on your example, the idea is doing a first test in the visitor to skip the file as early as possible and avoid visiting all its subnodes.

```
def funcdefn_visitor(self, node, parent, userdata):

    # You might want to change the test here
    if node.location.file.endswith("/stdio.h"):
        print "Skipping 'stdio.h'"
        # Continue with next sibling
        return 1

    if node.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.FUNCTION_DECL: #gives function definitions
        self.func_defn.append(clang.cindex.Cursor_displayname(node))
        self.func_defn_line_no.append(node.location.line)
        self.func_defn_col_no.append(node.location.column)

    print 'Found %s [line=%s, col=%s]' % (
        clang.cindex.Cursor_displayname(node),
        node.location.line,
        node.location.column)

    # Continue visiting recursively
    return 2

index = clang.cindex.Index.create()

tu = index.parse(self.filename)
#-- link cursor visitor to call back to give function definitions
clang.cindex.Cursor_visit(
    tu.cursor,
    clang.cindex.Cursor_visit_callback(self.funcdefn_visitor),
    None)
```

---

Now I'm not an expert of [`cindex.py`](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/tags/checker/checker-234/bindings/python/clang/cindex.py) (`libclang`'s python API), but I think your example follows the C API concepts rather than the python ones. Quoting from the documentation (emphasis mine):

> This module provides an interface to the Clang indexing library. It is a
>   low-level interface to the indexing library which attempts to match the Clang
>   API directly while also being "pythonic". Notable differences from the C API
>   are:
>
> - string results are returned as Python strings, not CXString objects.
> - null cursors are translated to None.
> - **access to child cursors is done via iteration, not visitation.**

Although `cindex.py` binds `Cursor_visit` to [`clang_visitChildren`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__CURSOR__TRAVERSAL.html#ga5d0a813d937e1a7dcc35f206ad1f7a91), it doesn't even export the [`CXChildVisitResult`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__CURSOR__TRAVERSAL.html#ga99a9058656e696b622fbefaf5207d715) enum, meaning that you need to hardcode values for `Break`, `Continue` and `Recurse`. The pythonic way of doing things consists in iterating on children nodes, as returned by the `Cursor.get_children()` method. An example is given in these SO answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17192971/1225607), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16770339/1225607)), which you can adapt to filter out nodes based on the source file.